# Java Graphics Full Screen Mode not Registering Keyboard Input

Tags: java, canvas, awt, paint, keylistener

I'm trying to write a full screen application that takes keyboard inputs. I've tried adding keylisteners to my JFrame and now to a canvas within the JFrame and setting them both as focusable but it doesn't seem to be registering anything at all. Is there something special I have do to in full screen mode to get it to register my keyEvents? Any help greatly appreciated. (display is just an extension of JFrame with no changes yet)

```
public class chanceCore implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener {

boolean isRunning = true;
display frame;
Canvas canvas;
GraphicsDevice device;
GraphicsEnvironment environment;

public chanceCore() {
    setUp();
    run();
}

public void setUp() {
    frame = new display("CGE");
    canvas = new Canvas();
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    canvas.addKeyListener(this);
    canvas.addMouseListener(this);
    canvas.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        draw(canvas.getGraphics());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344823/how-can-i-listen-for-key-presses-within-java-swing-accross-all-components  ?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. How could I fit it in to this example here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. After calling setFullScreenMode(), just add these two lines.
When we enter full screen something goes wrong,

```
frame.setVisible(false);
```