# Adding a KeyListner to a robot.mousePress and mouseRelease

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had put some code together to make this robot.mousePress and robot.mouseRelease program which I can set to click every 500 milliseconds. The only thing is that when I turn on the program it works just fine. Turning it off is the problem. I have to fully exit eclipse just to make the program stop.

How and where in the code would I add a keyListner so I could press a button to stop the program from running without having to exit the ADT?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class AutoClicker {

public static int rate = 0;

public static void main (String[] args) {

while (rate == 0){
try{
System.out.println("Speed of the auto-clicker (in miliseconds):");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
   rate = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
   if (rate < 500) {
   rate = 0;
   System.out.println("Must be at least 500 miliseconds.");
 }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
System.out.println("Error - please try again.");
}
} catch (IOException e) {}

}
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rate);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        } 
    }catch (AWTException e) {}
  }

}
```

Comment: In eclipse above the console window do you not have a stop icon (red square)

Comment: Indeed, but when I run the program the button isn't useable. Plus, for future refrence I might want to make a client to run this program, so I will need to learn how to use a event key in it anyways. @clairharrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a global key listener using this.
[How can I listen for key presses (within Java Swing) across all components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344823/how-can-i-listen-for-key-presses-within-java-swing-accross-all-components)
The infinite while loop at the end is the culprit here. Change it to a boolean variable which will be set to false by your listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(rate);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

This looks like the source of your infinite looping. Maybe try to implement some type of boolean variable which you can modify whenever you want your program to stop.