# Java/Swing - Creating Hotkeys

Tags: java, swing, components

I have a JFrame with multiple components on it, and I am not able to have the keyPressed event from the JFrame called because the frame is never focused, and the event only works when it is focused. How should I make a similar event but only have it work when the window is focused, not just the individual component?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is the answer, but it'd be a link only answer, so :( - but yes, it might be a good close reason as nothing else is going to answer the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can best be answered by reading the [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread on this site that does it extremely easily, no need for key bindings or anything. All this thing is, is an overrided method of dispatchKeyEvent; I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but it works for me

Here's a link to the thread
[How can I listen for key presses (within Java Swing) across all components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344823/how-can-i-listen-for-key-presses-within-java-swing-across-all-components)

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
    .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Got key event!");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to place a JPanel in the JFrame, then do everything using that JPanel instead of the JFrame.