# How to make Enter key and Submit button have same ActionEvent?

Tags: java, swing

So I have a Submit button with an `ActionEvent` that consists of around 50 lines of code. How would I assign the exact same `ActionEvent` for the `JFrame` as the Submit button whenever it detects the Enter key being pressed? This is what my Submit button's `ActionEvent` looks like

```
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // miscellaneous code that needs to be repeated for 'Enter' key press
           }
        });
```

What and where would the code for giving the JFrame the same `ActionEvent` as the Submit button go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344823/how-can-i-listen-for-key-presses-within-java-swing-across-all-components

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and in particular [`JRootPane#setDefaultButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-)

When you have components which may consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (like text fields), you might need to consider using the key bindings API

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter.pressed");
am.put("Enter.pressed", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnSubmit.doClick();
    }
});
```

Now, about now, I might consider making an `Action` which be applied to both the `JButton` and key binding

Have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a more correct swing way, but this should do the trick:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
}
btnSubmit.addActionListener(listener);
btnEnter.addActionListener(listener);
```

Comment: Enter as in the Enter key on the keyboard. Not an Enter JButton.

Comment: @btrballin might be worth mentioning that in your post :)

Comment: It looks like my description says Enter button but the title says Enter key.

Comment: @btrballin, yep, see that now.

Comment: Can you please update your answer so that it is for the Enter *key* and not an Enter *button*?

Comment: @btrballin, I don't have an answer as I'm not familiar with Swing. Though I suspect it would look quite similar. I can delete this answer if you'd like.

Comment: No Worries. I figured out a way where I create a KeyListener and use `btnSubmit.doClick()` within the `KeyPressed()`method to make it auto-click the submit button whenever the Enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the `.doClick()` method on the Submit button and create a `KeyAdapter`:

```
    KeyAdapter Enter = new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                btnSubmit.doClick();
            }
        }
    };
    txtField1.addKeyListener(Enter);
    txtField2.addKeyListener(Enter);
```

Comment: So, unless the component which the `KeyListener` is registered to has focus, a `KeyListener` won't work.  As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid using `KeyListener` with text components. There are also simpler and easier ways to achieve the same result (rather than having to register a `KeyListener` to dozens of components)