# Java Swing: How can I change a button's text when the Alt key is held?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a Swing gui I'm working on. I have a "Save" button, and I want it to delete an entry instead of saving if it's clicked when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is held down. Checking whether alt is held when the button is clicked is no problem. That's not what this question is about.

I want the text of the "Save" button to change to "Delete" when <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed, and back to "Save" when <kbd>Alt</kbd> is released.

I've tried adding a KeyListener to my JPanel but it doesn't seem to activate, possibly because the panel itself doesn't have the focus because focus is on one of its children.

I've tried a key binding via JComponent InputMap and ActionMap, but I can't figure out a KeyStroke which corresponds to just the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. My unsuccessful best guess at how that would look:

```
myPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("alt"), "altKey");
myPanel.getActionMap().put("altKey", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        log.info("alt has been pressed.");
        saveButton.setText(event.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT ? "Delete" : "Save");
    }
});
```

How can I get code to execute when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key itself is pressed/released, regardless of where the focus is in the window?

Comment: You listening to the wrong event. `ActionEvent` is used when an user action is exerted on a Swing (or AWT) component. You need listen for a `KeyEvent`, specifically, the ALT key press.

Comment: Try the answer to [Listen to key events across all components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5345036/16653700).

Comment: This is a good read on Key Events and how to listen for them: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: @AliasCartellano I've got a working KeyEventDispatcher that correctly detects if Alt is pressed/released. There seems to be a delay *sometimes* between when I press Alt and when the key event is dispatched.

Comment: @Martin for key binding, you may want to try `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle key events regardless of which element currently has the focus, use a KeyEventDispatcher attached to the current KeyboardFocusManager, e.g.:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
    .addKeyEventDispatcher((KeyEvent event) -> {
        if (event.isAltDown()) {
            saveButton.setText("Delete");
        } else {
            saveButton.setText("Save");
        }
        return false; // `false` allows further handling by other code
    });
```

Thanks to @AliasCartellano

Note: there does seem to be a small, unpredictable delay between when you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and when the event fires. Maybe because it's a modifier key? I'm unclear on whether that delay can be eliminated.